# I want to list on HTML table the 2 directories

Tags: php

I want to list down the files inside the 2directories but I received these errors:

Argument #1 is not an array in C:\wamp\www\new.php on line 62:

```
$directory = '/openssl/bin/';
$extension = '.pem';
$directory2 = '/openssl/try/bin/';
$extension2 = '*.*';

if ( file_exists($directory) ) {
   foreach(glob($directory.'*'.$extension) as $file){
        foreach(glob($directory2.'*'.$extension2) as $file2){
            $result = array_merge($file, $file2);   // line 76 error 1

?>
    <tr >
```

i want the output to be the list of filenames inside the 2 directories

```
        <td> <?php echo basename($result); ?></td>  // this should be list all the filename inside the 2 directory in table
```

file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\wamp\www\new.php on line 76   *line 76 below*

```
$data = openssl_x509_parse(file_get_contents($result));
```

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: `  <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="ifile[]" value="<?php echo $result; ?>" /></center></td>
  <td> <?php echo basename($result); ?></td>  `

i want to list down the filenames inside of the 2 directories

Comment: Not too sure what you want, maybe try this: http://pastebin.com/ZZ0ydVQY

Answer (score 0):

Hi The glob require the physical path to the file. So try to run this code

```
$dir = __DIR__;

$directory = $dir.'/openssl/bin/';
$extension = '.pem';
$directory2 = $dir.'/openssl/try/bin/';
$extension2 = '*.*';

if ( file_exists($directory) ) {
    $myArr = array_merge(glob($directory.'*'.$extension), glob($directory2.'*'.$extension2));
    foreach($myArr as $file){
        echo $file;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: i remove the DIR i just messed up with the code execution of glob thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php



$directory = '/openssl/bin/';
$extension = '.pem';
$directory2 = '/openssl/try/bin/';
$extension2 = '*.*';

if ( file_exists($directory) ) {
    $myArr = array_merge(glob($directory.'*'.$extension), glob($directory2.'*'.$extension2));
    foreach($myArr as $file){
        echo $file;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

?>
```

thanks for the help volkinc and to the other share their comments and suggestion i got the answer here i`m just a little confuse on glob execution code thanks for arranging it for me volkinc 
Cheers!!